# FBSDK FBSDKLoginManager and SFSafariViewController won't close

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdk, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm working with the latest FBSDK, using the FBSDKLoginManager to login. I have it all working, but one thing I cannot figure out is why SFSafariViewController is completely unresponsive after the login redirect?

Here's code:

```
- (void) login:(void(^)(NSError *error, NSString * token)) completion {
    FBSDKLoginManager * manager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    manager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;

    if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        NSLog(@"already logged in");
        NSLog(@"%@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]);
        completion(nil,[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString);
        return;
    }

    [manager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] fromViewController:nil handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
            NSLog(@"fb token: %@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString);
            if(error) {
                completion(error,nil);
                return;
            }
            completion(nil,[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString);
        });
    }];
}
```

This is what happens:

1. SFSafariViewController opens
2. Facebook prompts to login
3. Callback happens in AppDelegate.openURL:options: (I return by calling FBSDKApplicationDelegate.application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation).
4. Safari web view controller does nothing.

So the SFSafariViewController is white / blank. The done button does nothing. And I can't close it.

I also don't get the callback from the loginManager.loginWithReadPermissions method.

[image: Empty SFSafariViewController]

Has anyone experience this?

Comment: Facing the same error. Some progress?

Answer (score 3):

Actually they are 2 different openURL* callbacks that you need to implement, one for iOS8 and one for iOS9 :

```
@available(iOS 8, *)
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, source: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
{
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: source, annotation: annotation)
}

@available(iOS 9, *)
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool
{
    let source = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String // For ex: com.apple.SafariViewService from a SFSafariViewController
    let annotation = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: source, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [connect the app delegate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#delegate).

```
//  AppDelegate.m
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
    annotation:annotation
  ];
}
```

Comment: I did that, if you read my post #3 I explain how I call that.